# 403 Forbidden, only CakePHP - PHP-FPM - Apache 2.4 and mod_proxy_fcgi

Tags: php, mod-proxy, apache2.4, cakephp-2.4.7

This weekend I installed this software on my system.

Ubuntu 14.04LTS

- Apache 2.4.7 (from repository)
- PHP 5.3.29 (compiled) - with PHP-FPM
- (CakePHP 2.4)

My VHOST config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerAdmin martin.fink@sandstein.de
  ServerName snm.dev.mysite

  DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs/snm/svn/M/MS/my-site.de/trunk/web-site/

  ErrorLog /var/www/htdocs/snm/svn/M/MS/my-site.de/trunk/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/htdocs/snm/svn/M/MS/my-site.de/trunk/logs/access.log combined

  # symlink
  ProxyPassMatch /(.*\.php(/.*)?) fcgi://127.0.0.1:8999/var/www/sites/www.my-site.de/$1

  # Cake - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/htdocs/snm/svn/M/MS/my-site.de/trunk/web-site>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Everything runs fine

- snm.dev.mysite
- snm.dev.mysite/index.php
- snm.dev.mysite/de/service.php

except my CakePHP apps

- snm.dev.mysite/de/app1 etc.

All apps did work on Apache 2.4 and my former PHP installation (5.5?) (all from repository). Did I forget something to mention? You have any idea?

Thanks alot!

Comment: By the way ... snm.dev.mysite/de/app1/index.php does work!

Answer (score 0):

It was the file permission on the directory, which was the problem.

php-fpm wants to have 755 on directories .. I had 750. Maybe still a misconfiguration?